# Simulate No Internet Connection/Slow Internet Connection in Android Instrumented Test

Tags: android, kotlin, testing, connection, instrumented-test

I am writing a library that checks the the connection of the android device continuously and gives a callback when the device gets connected, disconnected or the internet connection becomes slow.

https://github.com/muddassir235/connection_checker

I want to write Android Instrumentated tests for this library and I need to simulate no internet connection as well as a slow internet connection.

```kotlin
package com.muddassir.connection_checker

import androidx.test.platform.app.InstrumentationRegistry
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4

import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

import org.junit.Assert.*

/**
 * Instrumented test, which will execute on an Android device.
 *
 * See [testing documentation](http://d.android.com/tools/testing).
 */
@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class ConnectionCheckerTest {
    @Test
    fun checkDisconnectedState() {
        val context = InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().targetContext
        InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync {
            val connectionChecker = ConnectionChecker(context, null)
            connectionChecker.connectivityListener = object: ConnectivityListener {
                override fun onConnected() {
                    assertTrue(false)
                }

                override fun onDisconnected() {
                    assertTrue(true)
                }

                override fun onConnectionSlow() {
                    assertTrue(false)
                }
            }

            // Disconnect from the internet. How do I do this?

            connectionChecker.startChecking()
        }

        Thread.sleep(30000)
    }
}
```

Comment: 1. Is using adb commands good enough for your purpose?
2. ConnectivityListener is part of what package?

Comment: Hi Gil, Connectivity listener is part of my own library https://github.com/muddassir235/connection_checker. I want to be able to run automated Instrumented tests which test multiple scenarios (Connected, Slow Connection, Disconnected) and was looking for some way to do it through code.

Answer (score 3):

Retrofit has a `retrofit-mock` module which offers a MockRestAdapter class whose purpose is to simulate network delay and errors.

This is a used in conjunction with the normal RestAdapter to create an instance of your service. You can see a full example in the samples/mock-github-client/ folder of the repo: https://github.com/square/retrofit/blob/master/retrofit-mock/src/test/java/retrofit2/mock/MockRetrofitTest.java

MockRestAdapter offers these APIs:

`setDelay` - Set the network round trip delay, in milliseconds.
`setVariancePercentage` - Set the plus-or-minus variance percentage of the network round trip delay.
`setErrorPercentage` - Set the percentage of calls to `calculateIsFailure()` that return true.
In your test, you can call `setErrorPercentage(100)` to guarantee that a network error will occur. By default the amount of time for the error to be thrown is anywhere from 0 to 3x the delay.

Comment: Actually I am using Volley for my requests. Great answer though.